# QGIS Serveur retourne une erreur HTTP à propos de l'extension Lizmap : 404

Tags: qgis-server, lizmap, nginx

I'm facing a problem to publish a map on lizmap web client. My server is a Debian 11 Bullseye, nginx with Spawn-Fcgi.

QGis server is 3.22.14 and is working (I successfully tested : http://localhost/qgisserver?MAP=/home/user/qgis_demo_projects/world.qgs&LAYERS=countries&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180).

Like it's said in lizmap documentation I installed 'Lizmap server' (v1.2.2).

But in lizmap administration, Information server is still showing following message :

```
QGIS Serveur

Nous ne pouvons avoir les détails sur l'installation de votre serveur QGIS (version, extensions etc.).
Soit la version installée du serveur QGIS est inférieure à 3.10, soit l'extension Lizmap n'est pas installé sur votre serveur, ou installé avec une version inférieur à 1.2.1. Mettez à jour QGIS Serveur au minimum à la version 3.10, et installez ou mettez à jour l'extension Lizmap serveur à la version 1.2.1 minimum, en lisant la documentation sur les variables d'environnement.
https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/install/pre_requirements.html#lizmap-server-plugin
QGIS Serveur retourne une erreur HTTP à propos de l'extension Lizmap : 404
```

And in lizmap log :

```
2022-12-22 15:23:45 172.16.251.59   notice  2022-12-22 15:23:45 [8] Trying to access array offset on value of type null /var/www/html/lizmap-web-client-3.6.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/lib/Server/Server.php   53

2022-12-22 15:23:45 172.16.251.59   notice  2022-12-22 15:23:45 [8] Trying to access array offset on value of type null /var/www/html/lizmap-web-client-3.6.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/lib/Server/Server.php   53

2022-12-22 15:23:45 172.16.251.59   error   L'extension lizmap_serverdoit être mise à jour.
```

Plugin lizmap server is succesfully loaded by QGIS server..:

```
● qgis-server.service - QGIS server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qgis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-12-22 09:08:23 CET; 1min 18s ago
   Main PID: 35457 (qgis_mapserv.fc)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 2336)
     Memory: 49.5M
        CPU: 723ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/qgis-server.service
             └─35457 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Server[35457]: Adding service EXPRESSION 1.0.0
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: Service "expression" loaded
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Server[35457]: Adding service LIZMAP 1.0.0
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: Service "lizmap" loaded
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: LizmapFilter.init
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: Filter "lizmap" loaded
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: Access control "lizmap" loaded
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Lizmap[35457]: Filter "get feature info" loaded
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Server[35457]: Server plugin lizmap_server loaded!
déc. 22 09:08:24 cartogs spawn-fcgi[35457]: 09:08:24 INFO Server[35457]: Server python plugins loaded
```

Seems Lizmap server plugin doesn't detect QGIS server..

I tried to change WMS url, change permissions, but without any success. Do you have any idea ? What can I test, I'm out of ideas ?

Comment: possible bug fixed? in https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG-3.6.md

Comment: If you can still replicate or if other people find this question, please share the logs when hitting the webpage. But indeed, error message have been improved in the meantime since the time of this question.